# Cobordism class of projectivization of a bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, fibre-bundles, cobordism

I was reading the book "Differentiable Periodic Maps" by P.E. Conner (1979). I am stuck at the following problem given at the end of section 21:

Let $\xi\to V^n$ be a $k$-plane bundle over a closed n-manifold then $[\mathbb{R}P(\xi)]_2=0$ if either $k=2$ or $n=1$.

I was able to solve the $k=2$ case just by using the expression of total Stiefel Whitney class for the projectivization of the bundle given at the starting of the section.
But I could not complete the second case using a similar approach.

Can anyone suggest an alternate approach?

Comment: The way I would try to do it would be to use the fact that every closed connected $1$-manifold is the circle, classify $k$-plane bundles over the circle (there aren't many), and check the vanishing for each of those.

Comment: @WillSawin That's what I was also thinking about, can you shed more light on classifying these k-plane bundles over S1.

Comment: Viewing $S^1$ as $[0,1]$ with $0$ and $1$ identified, since $k$-plane bundles on $[0,1]$ are trivial, a $k$-plane bundle is determined by its gluing map in $O(k)$. This gluing map only matters up to homotopy, so there is one $k$-plane bundle for each connected component in $O(k)$ - i.e. one with determinant $1$, the trivial bundle, and one with determinant $-1$, a nontrivial bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we can assume wlog that $\xi$ has an inner product.

Next, given a $2$-dimensional real vector space $U$ with inner product, let $QU$ be the space of self-adjoint endomorphisms of trace zero.  Given a unit vector $u$, define $\phi(u)\in QU$ by $\phi(u)(v)=\sqrt{2}(\langle v,u\rangle u - \langle u,u\rangle v/2)$.  This satisfies $\phi(-u)=\phi(u)$ and $\|\phi(u)\|=\|u\|^2$.  It therefore induces a map from the projective space $PU$ to the unit circle $SQU$, which is a diffeomorphism.

Now suppose that $\xi$ is a $2$-dimensional real bundle over a base $V$.  We can apply the above fibrewise to identify $P\xi$ with the circle bundle associated to $Q\xi$, which is the boundary of the corresponding disc bundle.  Thus, $P\xi$ is nullbordant.

Now consider instead the case of a vector bundle $\xi$ (with inner product) of dimension $k$ over a closed $1$-manifold $V$.  By dividing $V$ into path components, we reduce to the case where $V=S^1$.  Here standard arguments identify the total space $E\xi$ with $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^k)/\sim$, where $(t,v)\sim(t+1,Av)$ for some fixed matrix $A\in O(k)$. The isomorphism type of $\xi$ depends only on the path-component of $A$ in $O(n)$.  Because $-I$ acts as the identity on $\mathbb{R}P^{k-1}$, we also see that the diffeomorphism type of $P\xi$ depends only on the path component of $\pm A$ in $O(k)/\{\pm I\}$.  If $k$ is odd then $O(k)/\{\pm I\}$ is connected so $P\xi\simeq S^1\times \mathbb{R}P^{k-1}$, which is the boundary of $B^2\times \mathbb{R}P^{k-1}$.  The same applies if $k$ is even but $A$ lies in the base component.

The case where $A$ is not in the base component is less obvious.  When $k=2$ we get the Klein bottle, which is diffeomorphic to the connected sum of two copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$.  This is nullbordant by the first part of this answer, or by general properties of connected sums.  I think that there should be a direct geometric construction for $k>2$, but I don't see one just now.

If I remember rightly, there are various constructions like this in Stong's book on cobordism, but I don't have a copy.

Comment: I didn't really understand your approach, Can you give the general idea behind it, Also I think I have Stong's Cobordism theory notes If that's what you are following.@NeilStrickland

Comment: What step do you not understand?  I want to show that the cobordism class of $P\xi$ is trivial, so I give a direct geometric construction of a manifold $W$ and a diffeomorphism $P\xi\simeq\partial W$.